# Why doesn't arrive mail when the mail send from localhost to gmail?

Tags: php, cakephp

I send the mail from localhost to my gmail but the mail is not arrived at my gmail. Is not sent the mail to my gmail from localhost? How to send the mail to my gmail by using cake php?
I wrote the code for send mail by using cake php. It didn't have any error but not arrived the mail to my gmail. How to do that? Please explain me!

**I'm using xampp server and now test at localhost**

Comment: Google `cakephp Gmail` for some useful resources.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. Do you have a local MTA running on your machine or are you directly connecting to an SMTP server somewhere else? Where is your code that actually does the sending? Do your MTA logs have anything useful in them?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have a mailserver running on your local PC, so using the mail() function won't work (it's just a webserver, not a mailserver if my assumptions are correct in that you have just setup something like a WAMP stack).

It might be easiest to use your google mail account to send the emails via php, see here:
http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html

The second option is to use SMTP to your mail server:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

The third option is to set up MTA.

Comment: SMTP - send it with you gmail account. host: smtp.gmail.com port:465